# Index out of bounds array exception +Streamreader

Tags: c#

I have encountered an array index out of bounds exception based on the following codes:

I understand that readtoend method may disrupt the pointer for the streamreader, hence i implement the discardbuffereddata and seekorigin 0. However, im still getting an index out of bounds. help please? thanks!

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@".\Input\" + inServer + ".txt");
        readall = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string[] splited = Regex.Split(readall, "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        sr.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        sr.DiscardBufferedData();


    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                currLine = sr.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: which line is throwing the exception exactly? I don't see it from a quick glance.

Comment: The ReadToEnd() call in your code has nothing to do with the StreamReader, and never touches the file. The first two lines of code in your sample essentially do nothing.

Comment: sorry edited! wrong data pasted

Comment: Define "around" and tell us the exception type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try modifying your codes as follows:

```
        readAll = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        foreach (string s in readAll.Split(new char[] { '\r', 'n' }))
        {

            currLine = s;
```